# Can't install RTools

Tags: r, installation, cran

When I try to install RTools an error comes up. I can ignore the error and move forward but when I do this, I can't open it in R.

Here is what I did:

I downloaded the latest version of Rtools from here: 
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

I have the latest version of R so I selected the first option.

From there I ran the .exe file and checked the PATH box which would allow me to have it in an environment that I can run it.

[image]

Then at the end an error message comes up saying: 
[image]

Is this an administration issue?

Also is there an easier way to install Rtools from RStudio directly rather than downloading it from the internet? Possibly through devtools?

Comment: Do you use an account with administration rights on your system?

Comment: I do not, is there another way I can get Rtools besides downloading it from the internet? Can I do it through RStudio?

Comment: Have you tried installing in a nonstandard directory that you have access rights for?

Comment: Get someone with admin rights to install it for you ...

Comment: @Thomas, I haven't. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: During the install process, you'll be given the option to accept default settings or, alternatively, specify an installation directory.